# Excel: print list of column values based on corresponding row?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, output, lookup

SOLVED: I didn't realize this at first, but what I did was make a list of room numbers I needed to extract, and used an if statement. Something like:

```
if(<cell> in <list containing cell>, print email, "")
```

Working example:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,$S$6:$S$29,0)),C2,"")
```

Where S6:S29 is the list of room numbers I want.

My issue:
I have a somewhat specific question which I wasn't able to find an answer for. Basically what I want to do is given a spreadsheet like this:

```
name    email            room_number

John    john@email.com   312
Jake    jake@email.com   852
Ally    ally@email.com   328
```

I want to be able to print out a list of emails based on the room number. Such that I can type somewhere (852, 312) and it will print out or export the emails of Jake and John. I thought about using VLOOKUP but it doesn't seem like that helps much, so any help is appreciated.

Right now I have to look up room numbers through an online database, open up each person's profile, and copy and paste the email. I do this almost daily so I'm looking to automate the process so that I can just give it the room #s that I need emails for and then copy and paste all emails at once.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this. You could apply autofilter to the data and use the filter drop down for room to search. You could sort by room. Or you could create a pivot table that has a filter on it.

Comment: @TheTTGGuy I don't want to search for each individual room; the sheet I print is already sorted by room, I was wondering if there was a way to physically enter room #s and it prints out a list of corresponding emails, maybe through a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

I created named ranges, `name`, `email`, `room` for ease of reading the formula, but you can just replace this with the ranges.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(email,SMALL(IF(room=$E$2,ROW(room)-ROW($C2)+1),ROWS($C$2:C2))),"")
```

Say you enter a room number in `$E$2`, and below that you want the emails.  Use the above formula in `$E$3` and drag down.

[image]

If you don't use named ranges, the above would be:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$15=$E$2,ROW($C$2:$C$15)-ROW($C$2)+1),ROWS($C$2:C2))),"")
```

[image]

Edit: To do multiple rooms, just put another number in `F2`, and use the same formula in `$F$3` (but changing the `...$C$2:$C$15=$E$2` to `...$C$2:$C$15=$F$2`).

Comment: @ScottCraner - (does this work as pinging?) - don't you have a non-CSE formula for this? I dug and dug around for your comment that has it...but can't find it.